# ODBC Connection String Problem

Tags: sql, mysql, database, odbc

I am having major trouble connecting to my database via ODBC.

The db is local (but I have a mirror on a virtual machine), so I am trying to use the connectionstring:

> Dsn=MonetDB;host=TARBELL

where TARBELL is the name of my computer.  However, it doesn't connect. BUT, this string does:

> Dsn=MonetDB;host=localhost

as does

> Dsn=MonetDB

Can anyone explain this? I am at a complete loss.

I have taken down my firewalls (at least until I get this figured out), so that can't be the problem.

I eventually want to change the TARBELL to the mirrored virtual machine running another instance of the database.

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: If I had to wager a guess, I would say that the host entry refers to the machine on which the DSN has been created, not the server to which the DSN points.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for details on the supported syntax across all of the supported ADO.NET providers.

Answer (score 1):

DNS usually resolves `TARBALL` and `localhost` differently.  You can see with ping:

```
c:\>ping tarball
Pinging tarball [192.168.1.99] with 32 bytes of data:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^

c:\>ping localhost
Pinging tarball [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

The computer name resolves to the external IP, while localhost resolves to the special IP 127.0.0.1 that always points at the local machine.  Some installations of MySQL listen on localhost only, so if you specify the computer name, they stop listening.

This behaviour is configured using the `bind-address` option:

```
--bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Or the equivalent (MySQL also uses DNS to resolve hostnames):

```
--bind-address=localhost
```

To make the server listen on all interfaces, specify:

```
--bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

On Windows, MySQL reads configuration options from:

```
WINDIR\my.ini, WINDIR\my.cnf
C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf
INSTALLDIR\my.ini, INSTALLDIR\my.cnf
```

See the [MySQL manual pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

figured i'd post an answer to this here since i found this while searching for a windows monetdb connection string. this is the conn string i'm using and is working for monetdb 5:

```
DRIVER=MonetDB ODBC Driver;PORT=50000;HOST=<your host>;DATABASE=<your db>;UID=monetdb;PWD=monetdb
```

Comment: Thanks!, when you fail setting the connection string the error is **Driver's SQLSetConnectAtt failed** some entries talk about installing both x32 and x64 odbc's driver version (on a x64, of course) and no more entries found.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a "host" parameter for a `DSN` type connection string. `DSN`'s are either stored with the user, the system or as a file. The way you have referenced your `DSN` here, it is either stored under your user account or with the system. With a `DSN`, all the credentials and information about which server and driver to be used are stored in the `DSN`. If you want control over those parameters, you should consider a `DSN`-less connection string like so:

```
"Driver={Mysql}; Server=[server_name];Port=[port_number]; Database=[database_name];UID=[username]; PWD=[password]"
```